# Removing Action Bar completely from Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-fragmentactivity

I am currently trying to change the way an application looks.

The application uses 3 fragments that can be called base on network state changes. The fragments are all set to landscape, this leads the action bar to be a huge portion of the screen. I am trying to find a way to removed the action bar completely and allow the layout to expand to the entirety of the screen.

I have already tried things like:

getActionBar().hide();

Theme Changes

setSystemUiVisibility();

These option will either create a large bar across the screen where it should be or just display the Action bar anyways.

I assume this is something with the way fragments work that I just do not understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to completely remove the **ActionBar** (AppBar) completely from your App, then follow these steps:

> - Go to your **`AndroidManifest.xml`**
> - Edit this line:    `android:theme="@style/{theme}">` to `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">` or
>     anything that ends with `NoActionBar`.

And if you want to remove the **ActionBar** just from your `Fragment`, then add next code in the onCreateView() of the Fragment:

> ```
> @Override
> public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>
>     // create ContextThemeWrapper from the original Activity Context with the custom theme
>     final Context contextThemeWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.yourCustomTheme);
>
>     // clone the inflater using the ContextThemeWrapper
>     LayoutInflater localInflater = inflater.cloneInContext(contextThemeWrapper);
>
>     // inflate the layout using the cloned inflater, not default inflater
>     return localInflater.inflate(R.layout.yourLayout, container, false);
> }
> ```

Or if you want to remove the **ActionBar** from an Activity, add this one line of code to the onCreate() method of the Activity.

> `setTheme(R.style.{your style}`
>
> **Remember**
>
> - The {style} should end with `NoActionBar`
> - And most importantly, add the code **before** these two lines of code (add it to the top of the method):
>
>   ```
>   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>   setContentView(R.layout.{your layout});
>   ```

**Hope this answer helped!**

Answer (score 2):

If you are using AppCompatActivity then do it like this.

```
((AppCompatActivity )getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
```